# A list of tuples in javascript does not return the tuple

Tags: javascript

My array is the below.

```
const habit=[{"name":"eat_apple", "record":[("2020.11.16","Thu", 1)]}];
console.log(habit[0]['record'][0]);
```

I want to print ("2020.11.16", "Thu", 1), but the result is 1.
How can I get ("2020.11.16", "Thu", 1)?

Comment: `("2020.11.16","Thu", 1)` is an expression that resolves into `1`, you need to make it a string by wrapping it with quotes - `'("2020.11.16","Thu", 1)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS doesn't have tuples, so `("2020.11.16","Thu", 1)` is an expression that returns `1`

Try replacing the "tuple" with an array:

```js
const habit = [{
  "name": "eat_apple",
  "record": [
    ["2020.11.16", "Thu", 1]
  ]
}];
console.log(habit[0]['record'][0]);
```

Comment: I have been working on an issue for more than 4 hours ... and the reason for all this mess was only this. Thanks for the clarification!